# How to save an instance and update a reverse M2M field in a modelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Lots of questions cover saving instances before M2M relationships, however I have a problem achieving this when saving via a form with a `_set` relationship, which does not appear to be covered in other answers.

I have two models with an M2M relationship:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

When creating a new Author, I want to be able to set Publishers for that Author. Currently I handle this in the form:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    publishers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Publisher.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # If the form is used in a UpdateView, set the initial values
        if self.instance.id:
            self.fields['publishers'].initial = self.instance.publisher_set.all(
            ).values_list('id', flat=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(AuthorForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Update the M2M relationship
        instance.issuer_set.set(self.cleaned_data['issuers'])

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'publishers']
```

This works fine when updating an existing Author. However, when I use it to create a new one I get:

> `<Author: Sample Author>` needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I understand this is because the instance needs to be saved first, however in `def save()` I am doing this (`instance = super(AuthorForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `super` does not guarantee that it will create an instance. Because, form's [**`save(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method has a argument called `commit`, if the method calling the `save` is passing `commit=False`(for example: `form.save(commit=False)`), then it will not save the instance. So you need to explicitly save it. Like this:

```
instance = super(AuthorForm, self).save(commit=True)
```